Accessibility Components does *not* coincide with Path Connected and Connected Components for Length Spaces
I am working through "A Course in Metric Geometry" and I do not believe this exercise to be true:
Exercise $\boldsymbol{2.1.3}$
$3)$ Verify that accessibility components coincide with both connectivity
and path connectivity components of $(X, d_L)$.
My counter-example is $\mathbb{R}$ with the all continuous paths being permitted; however, $L: A \to \mathbb{R}_+ \cup \{ \infty \}$ assigns infinity to all paths. This space obviously has only one path-connected component, but each point in $\mathbb{R}$ has its own accessibility component (the set of points that are connected by finite length paths).
I have been thinking about whether or not my length space is well-defined because it is obviously not a metric space ($d_L (x,x) = \infty \neq 0$); however, I did not see that there is an axiom that requires that the length of constant paths must be $0$, rather it followed from additivity of lengths.
Thus, I think either the exercise is wrong unless I am misinterpreting the problem.
Edit: In this case there are actually no accessibility components because every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is not even accessible to itself.

Is there no relation between the topology of $X$ and the function $d_L$? The reason I ask is because ordinarily, when I see a metric, I think that the topology is generated by the open balls of that metric; but that clearly is not true with $\mathbb R$ and $L$.

The topology of $X$ and the topology generated by $d_L$ may differ. There is a proceeding exercise to show that the topology generated by $d_L$ can only be finer than the topology of $X$.

Then there is something big missing from your post, namely what general kind of relation exists between the function $L$ and the topology of $X$. I say that because, without any further conditions on $L$, there are a lot of functions $L$ such that the topology generated by $d_L$ is not finer than the topology on $X$.

@LeeMosher: The function $L$ is not arbitrary but satisfies certain axioms listed in the book on page 27.  Axiom 4 ensures that the topology defined by $d_L$ is finer than the original topology.

@MoisheKohan I thought that might be the case. But for the benefit of those site users who do not have the book in front of them, I had hoped to prod the OP into providing more substantial information about the nature of $L$.

Here is an answer of sorts. Your example also shows that their definition of a length structure is faulty since it allows $d_L(x,x)=\infty$ contradicting the definition of a metric (they do require $d(x,x)=0$). I think they should have added the assumption that constant paths are always admissible and have zero length (Gromov has this requirement in his book "Metric structures..."). Once you add this assumption, your example is not a length structure (even if you declare that constant paths have zero length) since $L$ is no longer continuous.
On page 27 (item 2) they write

"Observe that the previous property implies that $L(\gamma, a,a)=0$."

The trouble is that Property 1 does not imply that constant paths have zero length, but, clearly, this was their intention.
Incidentally, there is a set of errata to their book here. The mistake in the definition of a length structure is not listed. But they have a curious sentence regarding sections 2.4-2.5:

"Although we usually allow infinite distances, many statements here are obviously valid for finite metrics only. This condition has to be added where necessary."

Edit. Most likely, the intended formulation of Exercise 2.3.1(3) in the book was

Verify that accessibility components coincide with both connectivity and path connectivity components of $(X, d_L)$ where the latter is equipped with the topology $\tau$ defined by $d_L$.

With this formulation, it is clear that indeed a subset $E\subset X$ is a connected component with respect to $\tau$ if and only if it is a maximal subset of $X$ such that for every $x, y\in E$ there exists an admissible path $c$ in $E$ connecting $x, y$ and satisfying $L(c)<\infty$. From this, the exercise trivially follows.

Thank you, I figured maybe they were leaving some definitions out; however, I still cannot see how connected components coincide with accessibility components. Consider $T = { (x, \sin \frac{1}{x} : x \in (0,1) } \cup { (0,0) } \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ AKA the topologist sine curve. We admit all smooth paths and give it any Riemannian metric (since without $(0,0)$ it is a smooth manifold). Thus, when we join back $(0,0)$ we get a length space with metric corresponding to the Riemannian metric for every point except $(0,0)$ and infinity for distances between $(0,0)$ and anything else.

However, the topologist sine curve has one connected component, while having two accessibility components. Is there something wrong with my construction of this Length Space?

@2oovy: The result will have topology (induced by $d_L$)  different from the subspace topology induced from the Euclidean plane.

Ok, thank you for the help!

@2oovy: But this example shows that connected components do not coincide with path-connected components, of course. I think, they just stated the question poorly and actually they meant (when referring to connectivity and path-connectivity) the topology defined by $d_L$, not the original topology.
